# How can I evaluate a conditional selector expression from a string without using eval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Given the following string :

```
var expression = ".selectorA && (.selectorB || .selectorC)";
```

I plan to build a function that turns it into the following statement:

```
var result = ($(".selectorA").length && ($(".selectorB").length) || $(".selectorC").length)));
```

Essentially looking for the existence of these selectors given the rules of the expression. Provided that I do *not* know in advance the exact conditional expression in `expression` (the above is just an example), is there any way I can accomplish this without resorting to eval? This might seem a simple question, but I've been thinking about it for a while and so far I can't figure out another way.

Comment: How is this data getting into your JS?

Comment: If you don't want eval, you need a grammar parser, but what's wrong with eval?

Comment: @Sam via ajax, it's not user input, just a series of strings coming from the server. The reason I want to use to use a string even though it is not input is just for storage purposes.

Comment: @thg435 it could perhaps work in this scenario, I was just wondering if I could avoid it somehow just in case.

Comment: @Mahn: one can put together a quick'n'dirty regex stuff for that, but it will be fragile by definition. The only real alternative to eval is to define a grammar and to write a proper parser for it (or to use a generator like jison).